# Prove that set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider set C such that $C = \left\{  c | c = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{c_i}{5^i}   \right\} $ where each $c_i$ is either 2 or 4. Show that set $C$ is closed.

Attempt:
I tried to use the definition of a closed set in terms of it's limit points. And it seems obvious to me that the points c are the limit points since I can find two points as close to each other as I want them to.

But I struggle to prove that other points are not limit points for the same reason, intuitevely it seems like points are very close to each other, hence I struggle to make an open ball without elements of $C$ in it.

How shall I proceed?

Thank you

Comment: Prove that the complement is open.

Comment: This set is very similar to Cantor's middle third set. The techniques for proving that the Cantor set is closed will probably work in this case.

Comment: I tried to prove that the complement is open, but I didn't manage to construct appropriate radius for an open ball

Answer (score 0):

$C$ is a subset of the base $5$ numbers between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$. If $x$ is any real number we can express it as a base $5$ number where the fractional part is $\{c: c=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{c_i}{5^i}\}$ where $c_i\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Therefore, if $x\notin C$, either $x\lt \frac{1}{2}$, $x\gt 1$ or $x$ differs from $2$ and $4$ in at least one of the $c_i$.

If $x\lt\frac{1}{2}$ or $x\gt 1$ we can find an open interval separating $x$ from $C$.

If $x$ differs from $2$ and $4$ in one or more of the $c_i$s, let $c_k$ be the smallest one. Then the distance from $x$ to any other point in $C$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{5^k}$ so the open ball of radius $\frac{1}{5^{k+1}}$ about $x$ is not contained in $C$.

Therefore, the complement of $C$ is open and $C$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of the argument similar to yours but was struggling with irrational numbers. Didn't know you could represent any real number with a fraction part as in set $C$. Are there any resources online that explain this way of representing reals?

Comment: You can do a Google search for base n numbers but notice that a decimal number like 10.235 is $1\cdot 10^1+ 0\cdot 10^0 + 2\cdot 10^{-1} + 3\cdot 10^{-2}+ 5\cdot 10^{-3}$. Do you see the similarity?